# How to check if current EST time is between 00.00.00 - 00.00.10

Tags: php, cron

Check if the current EST time is between midnight(00:00:00) and 00.00.10

I want to run a cron job at midnight , But i want to be sure that cron job never call the script after 00.00.10 , I mean there must be maximum 10 seconds dealy in cron job(due to any reason)

So my question is how to check if the current est time is between 00.00.00-00.00.10

```
 if($current_est_time is 00.00.00 - 00.00.10){
  // Run the code 
     }
else{
   die("Sorry cron job was not called at correct time")
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$now = new \DateTime(
    'now',
    new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York')
);

$formatted = $now->format('H:i:s');

if ('00:00:00' <= $formatted && '00:00:10' >= $formatted) {
    // good time
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Yes ! Works great ! Thanks !

Comment: OH, Sorry, I forgot :)